# Process multiple update nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a function to update some values from a subdocument, but I am having troubles updating the data

```
  let query = InvoiceModel.find({
    is_draft:false
products.product: productid
  })

  query.exec(function (err, data) {
    if (data) {
      data.forEach(function(si) {
        let saleinvoice_id = si._id
        console.log(saleinvoice_id);
        InvoiceMovement(invoice_id, si)

      })
    }
  })
```

In the InvoiceMovement function I search for the record in the collection PRODUCT to update and try to update the array like this:

```
       productModel.findOneAndUpdate({
          _id: product_id,
          'warehouses.warehouse': warehouse_id
        }, {
          $set: {
            "warehouses.$.stock": stock_data,
          }
        }, function (errwu, wupdated) {
          if (errwu) {
            console.log(errwu);

          }
          if (wupdated) {

            console.log(wupdated);
          }
        })
```

But not all the data is processed.

For an specific ID I have 4 invoices records, but only two or less affect the value to update in the product collection

I try using [async.forEach](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) , but I get the same result.

UPDATE

Schemas:

INVOICE

```
const InvoiceSchema = Schema({
  invoice_number: {
    type: String,
  },
  products: [{
    product: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'products',
      required: [true, 'Producto no puede estar vacio']
    },
    warehouse: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'warehouses'
    },
    work_order: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'work_orders'
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'Cantidad no puede estar vacio']
    },
    base_price: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Valor Unitario no puede estar vacio']
    },
    sale_price: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Valor Unitario no puede estar vacio']
    },
    discount: {
      type: String,
      default: "0.00"
    },
    subtotal: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    tax: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    total: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

PRODUCT

```
const productSchema = Schema({
  code: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    required: [true, 'Nombre no puede estar vacio']
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Descripcion no puede estar vacio']
  },
  unit: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    required: [true, 'Unidad no puede estar vacio']
  },
  exempt: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  product_category: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'product_categories',
    required: [true, 'Categoría de Producto es requerida']
  },
  base_price: {
    type: String,
    default: "0.00"
  },
  unit_cost: {
    type: String,
    default: "0.00"
  },

  warehouses: [
    {
      warehouse: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'warehouses',
        required: [true, "Seleccione una caracteristica"]
      },
      stock: {
        type: Number,
      },
      unit:{
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  subproducts: [
    {
      subproduct: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'characteristics',
        // required: [true, "Seleccione una caracteristica"]
      },
    }
  ],
  stock: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
}, {timestamps: true});
```

From the Invoice Schema I go through the products array, to get the product ID and the quantity, with that data I update the stock in the warehouses array inside the PRODUCT schema.
I Need to do this for every Invoice.
One invoice can have many product registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one way you can do this. However, this might be easier if you use `mongoose.promise`.

```
InvoiceModel.find({}, 'products', function(err, invoice) {
  if(err) throw err
  const products = invoice.products
  // Loop through all the objects in the array 
  products.forEach(function(productsObj) {
    // Get the product model for each product
    ProductModel.findById(productsObj.product, 'warehouses', function(err, product) {
      if(err) throw err
      // Get a new array of only ids
      const warehousesIds = product.warehouses.map(warehousesObj => {
        return warehousesObj.warehouse
       })
      // Get the index of the current warehouse in the warehouses array in your product model
      const warehouseIndex = warehousesIds.indexOf(productsObj.warehouse)
      // Check if warehouse exists and if so assign the new value
      if(warehouseIndex > -1) product.warehouses[warehouseIndex].stock = productsObj.quantity
      // Save your model
      product.save()
    })
  })
})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't need to save the parent, I need to read the parent and get some data to make mathematical operations, then save the mathematical operations in other collection. Thanks for the reply @JazzBrotha

Comment: Ok. Can you share your schemas?

Comment: As can you see the I only need the product ID and the quantity, search the product and update the stock in the warehouse array in the schema PRODUCT

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer. Hope this is what you are after.

Comment: Indeed using Promise and async.eachSeries, the function works perfectly, Thanks